# Installing MacVim after having already configured Vim

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, macvim

This question could sound trivial, but i want to be sure of what i'm doing before trying something new. 
I have an already configured Vim installation, which i have installed via `brew install vim`, and a `vimrc` file for my configurations. In order to properly install `MacVim` there is something i have to do for maintaining my plugins and `vimrc`? Or i just type `brew install macvim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on *where* you did your configuration. If you did everything in `~/.vim/` you don't have to fear anything.

Comment: Yes, i've all in ~/.vim/. In this directory i also have /bundle/, for plugins installed via Pathogen plugin manager, /colors/, /ftplugin/ and /autoload/.